# Is there a stepper for Materializecss framework?

Tags: material-design, materialize, uistepper, formwizard

Is there any way or any plugin to make a stepper using Materializecss framework and following the Material Design guidelines?

Answer (score 7):

Actually yes! There is this simple and small plugin made for create a stepper with Materializecss framework:

https://github.com/Kinark/Materialize-stepper

I hope you like it!

Comment: You are fool at acting 

Comment: A little ;D
Anyway, it's for the best of the community. Before I made this stepper, I was the one googling for it hahaha

Comment: how to use this with angular6